# How I tell which Internet provider my computer is using?

Tags: isp, provider

I have RCN as my internet provider and just signed up for Xfinity Comcast Internet and they told me that it is enabled. I'm trying to have minimal downtime without internet so I'm not how I can tell if my Xfinity internet is working or whether I'm still connected to the original RCN provider?

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of online services which will show you your public IP address. One of them (I stopped at the first) will also show the ISP.

[IP Address check with ISP information](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to google for "Who is my ISP" where the first link goes to: https://www.whoismyisp.org. It will also show you your IP address.